# Jquery datepicker showing wrong date for leap year

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, leap-year

I am using a date-picker in an old project and it is working fine
but it displayed wrong date for leap year for 29/02/2016.

This is displaying 01/03/2016 instead of 29/02/2016. 
Please help me for displaying proper date of leap year.

Visit:  http://2008.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePicker.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [ask]

Comment: I would guess it is a bug in the library. But as they talk only about jquery 1.1 and 1.2 on their page I would guess that it is not maintained anymore and that this won't be fixed. So you either need to look in that code yourself and fix tge bug or switch to another library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was actually reported in this particular date-picker back in 2010.  [See issue #195](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-datepicker/issues/195).  There's a workaround posted there - or rather a rewrite of one of the functions.

However, it's clear that this library has been abandoned, so my recommendation would be to switch to something else.  If your project is jQuery focused, try [the date picker control in jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).  If you don't like the overhead of  jQueryUI, it's been made available separately [here](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.HTML).

Comment: Thank you very much... Issue resolved by your reference of                See issue #195                                                                https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-datepicker/issues/195